# Is it possible to implement a defer statement with delimited continuations?

Tags: continuations

A defer statement takes another statement and evaluates the given statement at the end of the current function call. [See how Go does it.](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12)

Delimited continuations can be abused to provide throw/catch semantics. [See an example here.](https://gist.github.com/sebfisch/2235780)

Is there any way to abuse delimited continuations to provide defer semantics? Sorry if this comes off as nonsensical, I just had this weird idea.